# Блокировка клика для внутренних блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="gallery" onclick="return location.href = 'path/to/'">
    <div class="next"></div>
    <div class="prev"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы обработчик события `onclick`, повешенный на `.gallery`, не вызывался при клике на дочерние блоки. Как это сделать?

Comment: Прочитайте внимательнее, пожалуйста

Comment: Хорошо, слово "динамически" я, вероятно, спутал с "автоматически". Но переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы было понятно что вы хотите, всё же стоит. Например, вместо непонятного "убрать ссылку" (особенно учитывая что в вашем коде нет ни одного элемента `<a>`), написать, что вы хотите, чтобы обработчик события `click`, повешенный на `.gallery`, не вызывался при клике на дочерние блоки. Это если я правильно отгадал по комментарию к ответу что нужно.

Comment: Всё верно! Прошу прощения за свою неточность.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность добавить код после кода добавления блоков, то решение есть простое и короткое:

```js
$(".gallery").append("<div class='next'><div>xxx</div></div>");
$(".gallery").append("<div class='prev'></div>");

//добавляем обработчик события клика для блоков и блокируем всплытие события
$(".next,.prev").on("click", function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.next,.prev {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery" onclick="return location.href = 'path/to/'"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Если же такой возможности нет, то стоит переписать обработчик события `click` у `.gallery`:

```js
$(".gallery").on("click", function(event) {
  //клик по самому элементу .gallery можно не проверять
  if (event.target != this) {
    //так как внутри блоков .next и .prev могут быть "дети",
    //то нужные классы стоит искать в элементах от event.target до .gallery
    var $targets = $(event.target).parentsUntil(".gallery").addBack();
    if ($targets.hasClass("next") || $targets.hasClass("prev")) {
      //если у элемента, на который кликнули, или у его родителя есть нужный класс,
      //то блокируем всплытие события
      return false;
    }
  }
  location.href = "path/to/";
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.next,.prev {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="next"><div class="xxx">xxx</div></div>
  <div class="prev"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Не будет срабатывать на элементе `.next и .prev`, на элементах `<a>`.

```js
$('.gallery').on('click',function(e){
var click_class = $(e.target).attr('class');
if ( click_class === 'prev' || 
  click_class === 'next'  ) {
console.log('element clicked is',e.target)
} else {
return location.href = 'path/to/';
}})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
    click here
    <div class="next">Вперёд</div>
    <div class="prev">Назад</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если срабатывает верхний onclick на блоке с .next, у блока .next нет внутренней ссылки, но на неё распростраляется onclick .gallery. Я этого хочу избежать

Comment: @ВикторТимошков не знаю это ли вам надо. Не сильно доходчиво описываете что вам надо. Если чтоб не срабатывало при клике на вложенные элементы next,prev,a то вот вам отредактированный вариант. Описывайте каждый элемент что должно происходить при нажатии на него более подробно.

Comment: @EVG не, нет никаких `<a>`: есть только `.gallery`, `.next` и `.prev`. После редактирования вопроса стало, по-моему, понятно что и как.

Comment: @ВикторТимошковк вообщем смотрите...